# PostgreSQL group by higher then

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL (9.2) database from which I am trying to get some grouped data. The groups should be like:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, >5 (higher then 5)

Is this possible? And if it is, how?

What I have so far:

```
select secondary_diagnoses_count 
from admissions 
group by secondary_diagnoses_count 
order by secondary_diagnoses_count;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of you data would be nice, but in general you can use `case`:

```
with cte as (
    select
        case
            when secondary_diagnoses_count > 5 then
                '>5'
            else
                secondary_diagnoses_count::text
        end as grp
    from admissions
)
select grp, count(*)
from cte 
group by grp
order by grp
```

PostgreSQL also allows to use aliased columns in `group by` so it could be written like this:

```
select
    case
        when secondary_diagnoses_count > 5 then
            '>5'
        else
            secondary_diagnoses_count::text
    end as grp
from admissions
group by grp
order by grp
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f5f9c/2)</kbd>**

Comment: This works for me, thank you very much. I will accept it as the correct answer as soon as I can.

Comment: You could write it without cte. Just with `case` in `group by`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko yep, but I think you mean not in `group by`, but in `select`, and then refer it in `group by`, see updated answer. I'm mostly work with SQL Server and SQL Server doesn't allow that

Comment: @RomanPekar Postgres allow function calls and `case` statements in `group by`. [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f5f9c/4).

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko It's not what I've meant. If you need grp in `select` and in `group by` it's better to use it in `select` and then refer to it in `group by`, it's always good to keep your code DRY :)